# IdentityServer4 refresh token issue

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity, refresh-token

Does anyone know how I can request for refresh_token? I’m trying to get refresh_token when requesting for access_token. At the moment I’m getting this output.

```
{
“access_token”: “eyJhbGciOiJSU…Zp1eS1WLY2KW2cLvEHhfDfikAYhPEDbAHTvtQu_yBgRsRxhTTPA”,
“refresh_token”: null,
“expires_in”: “3600”,
“token_type”: “Bearer”,
“scope”: “app.api.whatever.full”
}
```

Hence refresh_token is null. Now I know you can’t have refresh token with grant type of client credentials. Therefore I have created another two clients one with grant type of password and other of grant type of hybrid. I also set the scope for both to offline access. When requesting for a token I get invalid_client. I’m stuck and I have no idea how to resolve this issue.
This is how I’m requesting for token:

```
public async Task GetUserToken(string client_id, string client_secret, string username, string password, string scope)
{
var client = new HttpClient();

var dict = new Dictionary();
dict.Add(“client_id”, client_id);
dict.Add(“client_secret”, client_secret);
dict.Add(“grant_type”, “password”);
dict.Add(“scope”, scope);
dict.Add(“username”, username);
dict.Add(“password”, password);

client.BaseAddress = new Uri($”{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host.Value}”);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(“application/json”));

var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, “/connect/token”) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict) };
var res = await client.SendAsync(req).ConfigureAwait(false);

if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
return Ok(res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}
return BadRequest();
}
```

Can anyone point out where I'm I going wrong here?

Comment: It seems, this question and the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62015023/unauthorised-client-when-requesting-for-token-using-identityserver4-net-core-3) has same cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue - I had my client configured for the Resource Owner Password Credential flow (`AllowGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword`) & I had enabled refresh token generation for the client (`AllowOfflineAccess = true`). Even so, upon each access token request, the `refresh_token` field was returned with a `null` value.

Turns out that the calling client application also needs to add an additional scope to explicitly tell IdentityServer4 that it expects a refresh token to be sent. In addition to any scopes you specify when requesting an access token, also include `offline_access` in the space-separated list. Once I added this additional scope, the refresh token started coming through.

In your specific example, a potential edit could be:

```
dict.Add(“scope”, $"{scope} offline_access");
```

You can use [this](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/aspnetcore2/topics/grant_types.html?highlight=offline_access#refresh-tokens) link to read about this requirement in the IdentityServer4 documentation. The relevant information is in the last paragraph & in particular, this sentence:

> To request a refresh token, the client needs to include the
>   `offline_access` scope in the token request (and must be authorized to
>   request for that scope).